# Jqgrid multiple grids on same page

Tags: jqgrid

How can I put multiple similar grids on same page and same table.a sample code will help.Here is what I am thinking
 Page

Table

Grid1   Grid2

Comment: Can you please describe your task more detail? I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: Currently I have a jquery page with one jqgrid with 3 columns . I would like to add 2 more jqgrid with 3 columns each on to the same page. This is my task.could you please point me to some sample code that does this please

Comment: You do not need any special thing. Just add two additional table tags with pager (if any) and write a code for the two grids the same way as the first one.